# Navbar container not using full length

Tags: css, containers, alignment, navbar

I have been following a tutorial to create a web app using React, but when creating the navbar, for some reason the conatainer does not use the full length... I have tried several things but can't seem to find the proper solution.

this is the css for both the navbar and the container:

```
.navbar {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(28, 27, 27) 0%, rgb(26, 23, 23) 100%);
    height: 80px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  
  .navbar-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

this is the boxes surrounding the container which I can't figure out:
[image]

Any help is welcomed, css is clearly not my strong suit...

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Navbar.css';
import { Button } from './Button.js';

function Navbar() {
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
    const [button, setButton] = useState(true);

    const handleClick = () => setClick(!click);
    const closeMobileMenu = () => setClick(false);
    const showButton = () => {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 960) {
            setButton(true);
        } else {
            setButton(false);
        }
        };

    window.addEventListener('resize', showButton);

    return (
        <>
            <nav className="navbar">
                <div className="navbar-container">
                    <Link to="/" className="navbar-logo">
                        ZYGO <i class="fas fa-dice-d20"></i>
                    </Link>
                    <div className='menu-icon' onClick={handleClick}> 
                        <i className={click ? 'fas fa-times' : 'fas fa-bars'} />
                    </div>
                    <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
                    <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Home
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/simulations' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Simulations
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/about' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                About
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        {/* <li className='nav-item'>
                            <Link to='/sign-up' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                                Sign Up
                            </Link>
                        </li> */}
                    </ul>
                    {/* {button && <Button buttonStyle='btn--outline'>ABOUT</Button>} */}
                </div>
            </nav>
        </>
    );
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: might be useful if you provided your JSX as well. provides context to which class is which

Comment: @JudeBobinihi added the navbar jsx

Comment: @Nico Please use this to show your output: https://codesandbox.io/ You can also try anything else that works for you.

Comment: for starters, remove the justify-content and align-items in the .navbar. irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you have set the *navbar* outside the *navbar-container*? Can you switch those two? I guess container is supposed to contain the navbar and css set on that class has width set to 100%.

But since navbar has no width set it goes and takes only the space it needs.